# AS3 Error #1009 Cannot access...null object ref

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, classloader

Hello I am placing a external .swf into my .fla on a certain window but I had the following error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at TestingOne/createPlayer()
    at TestingOne()

I tried putting this into into the external .swf but no success -

```
       {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
```

I added the following in the action layer frame:

```
stop();

function RoachWarsGame2(){
     loadPlayer()
   }

function loadPlayer(){
    var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
    my_loader.load(new URLRequest("TestingOne.swf"));
    addChild(my_loader);
    my_loader.x = -320.95;
    my_loader.y = -485.95;
}
```

But I don't see the game.  Nothing is showing at all. Can someone offer me a solution?  Thank you....

londonbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take off the stage part of that listener and it should work.

What your doing is asking flash to tell you when that object has finished being created and has been added to the Display List. Thus it is now safe to manipulate to your hearts content.

saying stage.add~ defeats the purpose.

Edit: You really need to have that ADDED_TO_STAGE in the swf your loading. That is the only way you can be 100% sure it is loaded up before you try to use it.

Here is basically how it should work...

First our external swf that we made that we are going to load up for testing.

```
package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ExternalSWFDocumentClass extends Sprite
    {
        public function ExternalSWFDocumentClass() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initializeThisClass);
        }

        private function initializeThisClass(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initializeThisClass);

            // I am now added to the display list. Have fun.
            // Now when Some other swf loads me up I will know
            // for sure I have access to the stage etc.

            // Below this is for testing
            var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sp.graphics.clear();
            sp.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
            sp.graphics.beginFill(0xccccff);
            sp.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
            sp.graphics.endFill();

            sp.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
            sp.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;
            addChild(sp);
        }
    }
}
```

Now since you said your wanting to load it from an FLA file you do it like this.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var file:URLRequest = new URLRequest("externalSWFTest.swf");
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteLoad);

loader.load(file);

function onCompleteLoad (loadEvent:Event):void
{
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

Edit: Reading  your post again makes me think this might not be the problem. It might be but might be something else given the error you got. There is no reason to addChild the loader or set it's x and y properties.

Comment: He's right the entire point of the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener is to be able to know when it's acceptable to reference the stage object within the local object scope. The local object only receives a reference to the stage when that display object has been added to the stage or a child thereof (on the display list), and therefore ultimately is a child of the stage since the stage is the root or global display object.

Comment: Hows that last one for a run-on sentence ;)

Comment: Well thanks I did remove the stage from the external .swf but still it's not showing though loaded in the .fla frame.  I came across this code which I placed on the action layer and thought would help but it didn't help either.

Comment: Sorry I pressed return and lost my previous comment.  I was saying this is the code I have on the action layer on the .fla frame.

Comment: lol Sorrystop();

function RoachWarsGame2(){ 

loadPlayer() }

function loadPlayer(){

var appDomainA:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(); 
 
var contextA:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, appDomainA); 
var my_loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
my_loader.load(new URLRequest("TestingOne.swf"), contextA); 
my_loader.x = -320.95; 
my_loader.y = -485.95;
trace();

}

Comment: I think it's not loading because the external .swf has it's own actions because when I load a .swf that has no actions or AS3 code it loads.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer for you see if you can get it from there.

Comment: Hello Again, Feltope.  I aspire to one day be like you! :) It's working!! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.  Cheers x